# Algorithm - how to fast make sure elements unique from each group

Tags: python, algorithm

Don't know how to explain the problem in a title.

Here's the problem:

Assume we have 4 group:

```
(a, b, c, d)
(e, f)
(g, h, i)
(j, k, l, m, n)
```

Now I'm given a 4 elements tuple, for example `(a, e, h, m)`, neither 2 comes from one group, so I return True. If given `(a, b, e, g)`, then `a, b` are from one group, return False.

Then here's my current idea, I give each element an id start with group number and test for duplicate.

```
g1 = ['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d']
g2 = ['2e', '2f']
g3 = ['3g', '3h', '3i']
g4 = ['4j', '4k', '4l', '4m', '4n']


def test(elements):
    if len(elements) != 4:
        return False

    stack = []
    for e in elements:
        mark = e[:1]
        if mark in stack:
            return False
        stack.append(mark)

    ga = set(g1 + g2 + g3 + g4)
    return set(elements).issubset(ga)


print test(('1a', '1b', '2e', '3g'))
print test(('1a', '2e', '3g', '4m'))
```

But I think the string compare is not a very elegant solution, can this be done by another faster algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all the elements are hashable, I would use a `set.intersection`:

```
g1 = set(['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d'])
g2 = set(['2e', '2f'])
g3 = set(['3g', '3h', '3i'])
g4 = set(['4j', '4k', '4l', '4m', '4n'])

sets = [g1,g2,g3,g4]
test_this = ['1a','2e','3g','4j']

all(len(s.intersection(test_this)) <= 1 for s in sets)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to change the type of g1,g2 ... you can change the type of `test_this`:

```
g1 = ['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d']
g2 = ['2e', '2f']
g3 = ['3g', '3h', '3i']
g4 = ['4j', '4k', '4l', '4m', '4n']
lists = [g1,g2,g3,g4]
test_this = set(['1a','2e','3g','4j'])

all( len(test_this.intersection(lst)) <= 1 for lst in lists )
```

The beauty here is that `all` is smart enough to short-circuit -- and since we're using a generator expression, we don't need to calculate all the intersections up front.  Python will only keep calculating the intersections as long as all the previous intersections had length less than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Just playing around in the interpreter, same as mgilson, but you don't need to check `len()`, an existing set() evaluates to True.

```
>>> g1 = ['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d']
>>> g2 = ['2e', '2f']
>>> g3 = ['3g', '3h', '3i']
>>> g4 = ['4j', '4k', '4l', '4m', '4n']
>>>
>>> groups = (g1, g2, g3, g4)
>>> t1 = ('1a', '1b', '2e', '3g')
>>> t2 = ('1a', '2e', '3g', '4m')
>>>
>>> all(set(t2).intersection(g) for g in groups)
True
>>> all(set(t1).intersection(g) for g in groups)
False
>>>
```

Comment: I interpreted it as "I can grab 1 or 0 elements from each group, but not 2 or more".  This answer will allow grabbing 1 or more elements from each group.  If you want to grab 1 and only 1 from each group, then I suppose it should be `all(len(set(...).intersection(...)) == 1 for ... in ...)`

Comment: `len(test_this) == 4` will do the check.